# ReferenceError: nv is not defined in angular 2.00 rc4

Tags: angular

I am using ng2-nvd3 chart control in my angular 2 application (2.00 rc4)
But the following error is occuring when loading the page:

> ReferenceError: nv is not defined

Comment: **Note** *why don't use `Angular 4` instead of `2.00 rc4`*

Comment: Are this files loaded in exact order.d3.min.js,nv.d3.min.js,ng2-nvd3.ts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your JS are not in order, make sure to load them in following order.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
```

Load them up in index.html, before your system.js.config loading.

Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/T4i7Zh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you have included these libraries in exactly this order:

d3.min.js
nv.d3.min.js
ng2-nvd3.ts
Also, you can try to add the first two libraries to your index.html to determine if you have an import error: